# Which files of an autoconf project to put into .gitignore?

Tags: c++, git, makefile, autoconf

We have the [ctemplate](http://code.google.com/p/ctemplate/) library included in our git-managed project which is based on [GNU Autoconf](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/).

I would like to put everything which is generated by Autoconf into the .gitignore file to avoid conflicts if someone accidentally commits his platform-specific generated files.

Can someone tell me how to figure out the complete list of files autoconf generates/modifies for all platforms (Mac, Ubuntu, CentOS, etc.)?

Comment: Not an answer to the downvote question - wasn't me... but, it seems pretty trivial to 1) start with the files you wrote and commit them, 2) run `autoconf` and look at what files exist now - anything new was generated by autoconf - add those to `.gitignore`...

Comment: This might work for your local machine but autoconf can also generate stuff only on specific platforms.

Comment: Don't give commit privileges to anyone who would commit autotools-generated files :-P

Comment: adding ref to list : https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Autotools.gitignore

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is what I have in my various `.gitignore` (on Debian testing):

**Shared library:** (libtool)

```
/Makefile
/Makefile.in
/aclocal.m4
/autom4te.cache/
/config.*
/configure
/depcomp
/install-sh
/libtool
/ltmain.sh
/m4/
/missing
/stamp-h?
.deps/
.dirstamp
.libs/
*.l[ao]
*~
```

**Executable:**

```
/Makefile
/Makefile.in
/aclocal.m4
/autom4te.cache/
/config.*
/configure
/m4/
/stamp-h?
.deps/
.dirstamp
*.o
*~
```

You may want to adapt this a bit, but this is the bulk of it. `make dist-clean` followed by commit, rebuild, and finally `git status` may show you new files though, depending on what exactly your build generates.

Comment: hm, seems some of the files inside the m4/ directory are needed. I get configure.ac:65: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_COMPILER_CHARACTERISTICS

Comment: Are you using `autoreconf --install` first? I do, and it regenerates the `m4` directory.

Comment: I'd work from a `make maintainer-clean` rather than `distclean`.

Comment: +1, but `*~` and `*.o` should probably be globally ignored (eg, in `~/.gitconfig:[core]`)

Comment: For the bleeding edge, you might want to add `ar-lib` to this list.